# If the DataTemplate is nested in another Datatemplate it's hard the binding with a father-template property

Tags: silverlight, nested, datatemplate, visualtreehelper, findancestor

Have youI know that the problem has been many times discussed in the web. But mine is a particular case and I still haven't found the right solution.

Scenario: Silverlight 4 - A TreeView with data showed by two HierarchicalDataTemplate, one to show the first-level data (i.e. the data of the father-items of the TreeView), and one to show the second-level data (for the child-items). In the child-items template I have to bind the visibility of a control to a property of the data source class of the father template.

This is the XAML code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="modTreeArtDataParts2">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock
                Visibility="{Binding ???}"/>
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="modTreeArtDataParts"
        ItemTemplate = "{StaticResource modTreeArtDataParts2}"
        ItemsSource = "{Binding RicambiItemList}">

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TreeView
        ItemTemplate = "{StaticResource modTreeArtDataParts}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding RicambiList}"/>
</Grid>
```

If it was WPF I could write:

Visibility = "{Binding DataContext.Ori, Converter={StaticResource rVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"

... and it would certainly works. But I know that in Silverlight **FindAncestor as binding-mode with RealitiveSource is not supported**. The solutions in the web are all around the **scrolling down, in the code-behind, of the visual tree**. It doesn't matter if it's realized with a Behavior or with an Attached-Propery. The solutions are like this:

```
Public Class hideTextBlockBehavior
    Inherits Behavior(Of DependencyObject)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnAttached()
        MyBase.OnAttached()
        Dim g As Grid = FindVisualParent(Of Grid)(AssociatedObject)
        Dim o As customType = g.DataContext
        If o.hide Then AssociatedObject.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
    End Sub

    Private Function FindVisualParent(Of parentItem As DependencyObject)(ByVal obj As DependencyObject) As parentItem
        Dim objParent As DependencyObject = obj
        While obj Is Nothing = False AndAlso TypeOf obj Is parentItem = False
            obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj)
        End While
        Return DirectCast(obj, parentItem)
    End Function
End Class

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="modTreeArtDataParts2">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <il:hideTextBlockBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I used many times solutions like this, and they always works. But in this case my DataTemplate is **nested** into another DataTemplate then, when I'm in the "OnAttached" method, the property "Parent" of the "AssociatedObject" is nothing, then **I have no Visual-Tree to scroll**.

Have you got a suggestion?
Thank you in advance!
Pileggi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to pass a reference to your parent view model to the children on construction:

```
var itemVm = new ItemViewModel()
{
    Description = "Parent", ChildVisibility = "Collapsed"
}
itemVm.Children = new List<ChildItemViewModel>
{
    new ChildItemViewModel()
    {
        ParentVm = itemVm;
        Description = "Child"
    }
}
```

By doing so, you can easily bind to the property on the parent view model like so:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ParentVM.ChildVisibility}"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that, but it's a little redundant, isn't it?

Comment: It is somewhat redundant, although I think that most workarounds for Silverlight shortcomings (opposed to WPF's richness) lead to similar constructs. Personally, I find traversing the visual tree in custom code equally inelegant. Either upgrading to Silverlight 5, or using a converter would be other options. Possibly, you could go without the references if you would use a view model locator service as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the eric solution (taht force you to add the same property of the parent in the child class), the only way, I suppose, you can take, is to upgrade your application to Silverlight 5, that support FindAncestor with RelativeSource:

Visibility = "{Binding DataContext.Ori, Converter={StaticResource rVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"